# Inserting tuple values into mysql table using pymysql.cursor()

Tags: python, mysql-python, pymysql

**Step1**: Firstly i have connected to a db and from a mysql table pulled out all the rows from 2 columns     ***(idnum,clientname)*** 
***Eg:(1234,renolds),(1235,renolds2)***

**Step2**: Then each idnum has a seperate table 
***Eg:sample_divya_1234;sample_divya_1235,*** 
from each of these tables we need to take all emails and lnames.
 *(Note: each idnum has many email and lname records)*

**Step3**: All the clientnames taken in step1 are present in another table sample_divya3, so for each clientname need to pull out fname 
***Eg:(saha , renolds)***

**Step4**: Now email,lname,fname must all get dropped into a new table sql_table1

*prog:*

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from time import time
import datetime

conn=pymysql.connect(host= ,user='',password='',db='')


query = "select idnum,clientname from sample_divya1 where date(created_date)=date(now())"
cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
data = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("drop table if exists sql_table1")
sql_table = "create table sql_table1(email varchar(128),lname varchar(128),fname varchar(128))"
cursor.execute(sql_table)
for id,client in data:
    data = " select email,lname from sample_divya_"+id
    cursor.execute(data)
    conn.commit()
    df = cursor.fetchall()
    print df
    list_id="select fname from sample_divya3 where clientname='{}'".format(client)
    cursor.execute(list_id)
    conn.commit()
    data1 = cursor.fetchall()
    print data1
    print type(data1)
    for x,y in zip(df,data1):
        cursor.execute("""insert into sql_table1  values (%s,%s,%s)""", (df[0][0], df[0][1],data1[0][0]))
        conn.commit()
        dat_1 = cursor.fetchall()
        print dat_1
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

***getting output :***

```
+-----------------+----------+--------+
| email           | lname    | fname  |
+-----------------+----------+--------+
| abc@yahoo.com   | abcd     | saha   |
| xyz@gmail.com   | xyza     | hasini |
+-----------------+----------+--------+
```

***but required output:***

```
+------------------+----------+--------+
| email            | lname    | fname  |
+------------------+----------+--------+
| abc@yahoo.com    | abcd     | saha   |
| bcd@gmail.com    | bcda     | saha   |
| xyz@gmail.com    | xyza     | hasini |
| nag@gmail.com    | sai      | hasini |
| hij@gmail.com    | klm      | hasini |
+------------------+----------+--------+
```

**Input Tables:
    Sample_divya1:**

```
 +-------+------------+---
    | idnum | clientname | 
    +-------+------------+-
    | 1234  | renold    | 
    | 1235  | renold1    | 
   +-------+------------+
```

**sample_divya_1234**

```
   +-------------------+----------+
    | email             | lname    |
    +-------------------+----------+
    | abc@yahoo.com     | abcd     |
    | bcd@gmail.com     | bcda     |
    +-------------------+----------+
    **sample_divya_1235**
    +------------------+-----------+
    | email            | lname     |
    +------------------+-----------+
    | xyz@gmail.com    | xyza      |
    | nag@gmail.com    | sai       |
    | hij@gmail.com    | klm       |
    +------------------+-----------+
    **sample_divya3**
    +--------+------------+
    | fname  | clientname |
    +--------+------------+
    | saha   | renold     |
    | hasini | renold1      |
    +--------+------------+
```

Kindly help me out

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.cursor.execute("insert ignore into " + options.youtube_table_name + " (" + ",".join(data.keys()) + ") values (" + ','.join(['%s' for column_name in data.keys()]) + ")", data.values())
```

data should be a dictionary

Comment: Hi , i have updated the input tables also for better clarity i get the output from each table in tuple form i.e df,data1 are in tuple form                                       eg:      
  df:      (('abc@yahoo.com', abcd'), ('bcd@gmail.com', 'bcda'))
data1:  (('saha',),)

Comment: Hi , one more thing to add on i dont only have two feilds i,e email,lname i need to take many feilds approximately 11 fields from idnum tables, but for sample i have created this example.,dats y may be dictionary concept can't be applied.

Comment: somehow i feel mistake is in this only first records of df are taken :                      
  for x,y in zip(df,data1):
        cursor.execute("""insert into sql_table1  values (%s,%s,%s)""", (df[0][0], df[0][1],data1[0][0]))

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
for id, client in data:
    print "==========="
    data = " select email,lname from sample_divya_"+id
    cursor.execute(data)
    conn.commit()
    df = cursor.fetchall()
    # print df
    list_id = "select fname from sample_divya3 where clientname='{}'".format(
        client)
    cursor.execute(list_id)
    conn.commit()
    data1 = cursor.fetchall()
    print df 
    print "------------"
    print data1
    print "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
    data2= data1* len(df)

    print zip(df,data2)

    for x ,y in zip(df,data2):
        dat = """insert into sql_table1  values (%s,%s,%s)""", (x[0], x[1],y[0])
        print dat

    # dat = """insert into sql_table1  values (%s,%s,%s)""", (
    #     df[0][0], df[0][1], data1[0][0])
    # cursor.execute("""insert into sql_table1  values (%s,%s,%s)""",
    #                (df[0][0], df[0][1], data1[0][0]))
    # conn.commit()
    # dat_1 = cursor.fetchall()
    # print dat
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

===========================================

OUTPUT :

===========

('insert into sql_table1  values (%s,%s,%s)', ('divya@gmail.com', 'sai', 'hasini'))
('insert into sql_table1  values (%s,%s,%s)', ('sainag@gmail.com', 'nagandla', 'hasini'))
('insert into sql_table1  values (%s,%s,%s)', ('venu@gmail.com', 'venugopal', 'hasini'))

===========

('insert into sql_table1  values (%s,%s,%s)', ('pavan@yahoo.com', 'inaganti', 'saha'))
('insert into sql_table1  values (%s,%s,%s)', ('sahasra@gmail.com', 'sahasra', 'saha'))

===========

('insert into sql_table1  values (%s,%s,%s)', ('gopal@gmail.com', 'venugopal', 'chinn'))
('insert into sql_table1  values (%s,%s,%s)', ('vishnu@gmail.com', 'vishnu', 'chinn'))

===========

Explanation:

In the code above , the zip(A,B) was slicing the the length of tuple to the length of the smaller tuple object. So I matched the length of the tuples by duplicating the the tuple. Also please not that this solution only works when there is only one fname for all the client_num in the table sample_divya3.

Example:

```
>>> A=((1,2),(2,3))
>>> B=(('A',))
>>> zip(A,B)
[((1, 2), 'A')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in next way

```
cursor.execute("insert into sql_table1  values %s", (your_tuple,))
```

important that `your_tuple` should be `tuple()` not `list()`

Answer (score -1):

Got it finally:

```
  for id,filename,name,client in data_1:
        sql="select '{}',email,lname from sample_divya_{}".format(name,id)
        cursor.execute(sql)
        data_2=cursor.fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        data=list(data_2)
        df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

tried to put everything into one query pulled out data from two tables.
for tuple insertion i first converted tuple to a list later to a datafram and put that in csv